# Plymouth theme with sound

Tags: debian, audio, theme, plymouth

Is this possible? Just a yes or a no. I'm not sure where to look for good documentation on Plymouth theme creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it’s not possible. The best starting point for Plymouth theme documentation is [the Gentoo wiki’s theme creation page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Plymouth/Theme_creation).